# Does Cloud Spanner actually work with Hibernate DDL using PostgreSQL dialect?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, google-cloud-spanner

It seems a little bit strange that I haven't seen anyone else run into this problem: I'm trying to use Google Cloud Spanner as a drop-in replacement for PostgreSQL. My application connects to two databases, one which is local Postgres, and the other which is a Cloud Spanner database configured with Postgres dialect. I'm working with Java / Hibernate / Spring JPA.

*** Before I ask my question, I should point out that I'm glaringly clear on the point that Spanner does not support sequences.

I've tried this both with the Google Spanner JDBC driver and with PGAdapter and run into the same problem: When hibernate tries to do its DDL thing (I'm using hibernate.hbm2ddl=auto), it queries "select * from information_schema.sequences", which fails with "ERROR: relation 'information_schema.sequences' does not exist", naturally, since as I mentioned, Spanner doesn't support sequences. However this causes Hibernate to fail and not produce an EntityManager.

- Of course, if you use the Cloud Spanner hibernate dialect, you won't run into this problem. That is not an option for me because I *will_not* support two dialects of entity objects in my codebase. (If my entity objects are not portable, with the exception of sequences, then we're entirely missing the point.)
- Of course, if I turn hbm2ddl off, I would not expect to see this problem. I am not about to start manually maintaining my schema or creating tables either.

So my question is: Is this working for anybody else? Is anybody using PostgreSQL dialect for Hibernate + Cloud Spanner? And if so, ->***how did you get Hibernate not to query the information_schema for sequences***<-??? I don't have any sequences set on the entities destined for the Cloud Spanner database, but I do have entities with sequences destined for the other local PostgreSQL database. (As the two connections are separate from the driver-up, this shouldn't matter at all, but maybe it does somehow???)

I have tried this with all 3 JDBC options for Cloud Spanner, and all I have determined is it looks like Hibernate DDL + CloudSQL works, and Hibernate DDL + PostgreSQL dialect is broken. I would expect that, in the name of getting things to work, the information_schema.sequences relation would exist in PostgreSQL dialect databases, but would always come back empty when queried, and the statements that would fail would be ones that actually try to create a sequence...

...because making a Postgres dialect for Spanner databases, and having JDBC drivers speak it, but not supporting it via the Hibernate Postgres dialect is kinda like missing 99.99% of your target market... but what do I know? Maybe even if this is fixed, other DDL things would still break down-the-line?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the different options that you have listed:

1. Using the Cloud Spanner JDBC driver with the PostgreSQL Hibernate dialect is not supported. Especially DDL operations will fail (as you have seen).
2. Using the Cloud Spanner JDBC driver with the Cloud Spanner Hibernate dialect is supported (obviously).
3. Using the PostgreSQL JDBC driver with the PostgreSQL Hibernate dialect in combination with PGAdapter is supported, but with some limitations. See [this example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/pgadapter/tree/postgresql-dialect/samples/java/hibernate) for a small sample application that does not run into this problem. That sample also contains a list of supported features and limitations.

The problem might be related to the specific version of Hibernate that you are using and/or some specific configuration. Opening an [issue here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/pgadapter/issues/new) will make it easier to debug your specific situation.

Comment: Thanks Knut for the speedy and informative response! From the notes in your project, it looks like the answer is pretty clear: "Automated schema updates using hibernate are therefore not supported. It is recommended to set the option hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=none". Though there is a faint ray of hope in "Note that PGAdapter does support create table if not exists / drop table if exists." Presumably that means you expect "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create" or "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop" might work, so long as I'm willing to blow away parts of my database on startup. :/ I'll open an issue!